# Creating a tuple using knockout and typescript

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, visual-studio-2015

I use knockout, typescript and I want to create a tuple.

This is what I have tried:

Delcaring:

`public TestTuple: KnockoutObservableArray<number>;`

Initialising:

`this.TestTuple = ko.observableArray([0, 0, 0, 0]);`

Using:

`this.TestTuple()[0, 0, 0, 0] = new Array(); //this works in the "Immidiate Window"(VS2015)
this.UI_FourDimensionDataBindArray[0] = new Array();//this works, but this is not what I want`

What shall I change here ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
this.TestTuple([1, 2, 3, 4]) // set value of TestTuple
```

This is how you change the value of an observable in Knockout, regardless of whether you're using TypeScript or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but since you're trying to assign a single value (1 tuple), I would assume that you want to use an observable (with a tuple-signature), rather than an observableArray.

```
public TestTuple: KnockoutObservable<[number, number, number, number]>;
```

Assigning it a value, would mean assigning the entire tuple:

```
this.TestTuple([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```